# Ignore special meaning of characters in command line and handle them as strings

Tags: python, shell

So I need to write a program in python3 that will read in 2 command line arguments userName and passWord. What I am struggling with is the fact that if the user enters a character with special meaning in bash (e.g. ', \n, \b etc.) my bash executes it. What I need is to somehow ignore the special meaning of those characters and simply read them in as strings. I have no control over what the input is gonna be and I cannot tell the user to escape them. I am simply accepting whatever the user throws at me.

Comment: This isn't your problem to solve; whoever is running your program from the shell is responsible for knowing how to use their shell.

Comment: @chepner, but is there no way for me to handle it in my code?

Comment: You’re required to ignore all special characters, and cannot control the input or have it properly escaped? There won’t be any scenario in which the user actually wants a newline instead of `\n`, for example?

Comment: No; the shell processes what the user types, and gives you the result of that processing.

Comment: @AMC yes correct. So if user wants his password to be \n then I have to read that in as his password.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add each argument in double quotes "argument"

For example:

```
python myScript.py "peter" "my/weird%^#password"
```

Comment: I do not control  the arguments. With your example, my code will be tested with python myScript.py peter my/weird%^#password

Comment: How are you planning on calling the script then?

Comment: Through cmd. 
But I have to call it by: python myScript.py peter my/weird%^#password
I simply cannot do: python myScript.py "peter" "my/weird%^#password"
It is one of the requirements on the code.

Comment: @DenisShevchenko That simply isn't under your control. It is fine for your script to *expect* a password that can contain arbitrary characters, but how a user accomplishes that is entirely up to the shell they use to start your program; it's not something your Python implementation has any control over.